# Bluetooth headphones disconnect after a few seconds

Tags: bluetooth

I connect my Bluetooth headphones and after 4-5 seconds of speaking they disconnect. This problem exists on Ubuntu and Linux Mint, but not on Windows 10 or Kubuntu.

I tried removing blueberry and installing blueman, but no change. My system is up to date. I think this is the problem:

```
a2dp-source profile connect failed for 00:14:BE:71:4D:86: Device or resource busy
```

Thanks in advance for your help as well.

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20
DISTRIB_CODENAME=ulyana
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 20 Ulyana"
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="20 (Ulyana)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 20"
VERSION_ID="20"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=ulyana
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
cat: /etc/upstream-release: Is a directory
```

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b5)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port Mobile SATA AHCI Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF119M [GeForce GT 520MX] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0c45:8603 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3005 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR3011 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ lsmod | grep blue
bluetooth             581632  37 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
```

```
$ dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[   14.271831] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   14.271860] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.271866] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.271869] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.271875] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   29.468293] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.468296] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.468302] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   50.679218] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   50.679230] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   50.679237] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

```
$ rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-08-31 16:58:31 CEST; 16min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 725 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 6917)
     Memory: 2.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─725 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

aug 31 16:58:31 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
aug 31 16:58:53 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.32 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
aug 31 16:58:53 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.32 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
aug 31 16:59:27 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.32 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
aug 31 16:59:27 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: Endpoint unregistered: sender=:1.32 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
aug 31 16:59:27 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
aug 31 16:59:27 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.43 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
aug 31 17:01:45 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_14_BE_71_4D_86/fd0: fd(39) ready
aug 31 17:14:53 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: a2dp-source profile connect failed for 00:14:BE:71:4D:86: Device or resource busy
aug 31 17:14:56 linxmint bluetoothd[725]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_14_BE_71_4D_86/sep1/fd1: fd(37) ready
```

```
$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 74:2F:68:6B:20:E2  ACL MTU: 1022:8  SCO MTU: 121:3
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:9027 acl:118 sco:0 events:581 errors:0
    TX bytes:265424 acl:417 sco:0 commands:105 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0xfe 0x0d 0xfe 0x98 0x7f 0x79 0x87
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'linxmint'
    Class: 0x1c010c
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing, Object Transfer
    Device Class: Computer, Laptop
    HCI Version: 3.0 (0x5)  Revision: 0x9999
    LMP Version: 3.0 (0x5)  Subversion: 0x9999
    Manufacturer: Atheros Communications, Inc. (69)
```

Comment: I have [this](https://donjajo.com/bluetooth-fix-a2dp-source-profile-connect-failed-xx-protocol-not-available-linux/) in my bluetooth notes. I'd give that a shot first.